# Cannot add table element to page

Tags: structr

I follow the Getting Started document on Structr 2.0.1. When trying to add a table element to the page, nothing happens. After several attempts I lose the connection and reloading takes a while (locally on my Mac). Other elements like forms work fine.
I tried to recreate the structure for the table element using the bootstrap guide. However, anything within the div.class tag is just rendered as text in quotes but without any header or body tags.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Best regards,
Christian

Comment: How did you try to add a table element, was it a widget or a single table element from the HTML palette? If it was a widget, which one exactly?

Comment: Hello Axel, thanks for your response. I added a Bootstrap>Tables>Striped Table to the Container div tag. The page flickers shortly, but the element does not appear. Inserting e.g. a Panel is not a problem. Basically, I was at step 24 in the step-by-step tutorial in the Structr documentation.

Comment: That's strange. Could you please try with the latest 2.1-SNAPSHOT? This version is much move advanced and modern, and also stable enough (we run every production system on it already).

Comment: Thanks, Axel. That seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version 2.1 works...